# Timepicker widget doesn't show up correctly on Android 5

Tags: android

Hello friends I made an alarm clock and everything works great on android version 6.
In lower versions like android 5, my `TimePicker` has an issue (check my image below)

My code for `TimePicker` is:

```
<TimePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:numbersBackgroundColor="#FFF" />
```

And my activity's xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_mainnew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
```

[image]

Comment: can you try with android:numbersBackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"

Comment: It doesn't work @X3Btel